# Java Stored Procedures how to register out parameter properly

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So this is my stored procedure

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getStudentsName`(IN STUD_ID INT, OUT S_FIRST VARCHAR(255), S_LAST VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT first, last INTO S_FIRST, S_LAST
    FROM studentsinfo
    WHERE id  = STUD_ID;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is my java code:

```
String sql = "{call getStudentsName (?, ?, ?)}";
            stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);

            int studID = id;
            stmt.setInt(1, studID);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

            stmt.execute();
```

It's giving me "Parameter number 3 is not an OUT parameter" error. I've seen examples with only 1 out parameter so I'm not sure if I did the right thing since I have 2 out parameter.

Comment: The error is correct, your third parameter is not an OUT parameter. Maybe you intended to declare it as `OUT S_LAST VARCHAR(255)`, but that is not its current declaration.

Comment: So I need to change my stored procedure and declare the S_LAST as OUT? Is that right? Edit: Yes the S_LAST was declared as IN so I just changed it to OUT, thanks.

Comment: Yes, otherwise it is not an OUT parameter. A parameter is `IN` by default, unless explicitly specified. See also the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)